# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist with JPA entityManager.createQuery()

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am using **JPA** **createquery** API to fetch the data.

Here is my query data

```
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;
    @Override
    public List<String> fetchAllReleaseNumbers() {

        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT release FROM ReleaseModel", String.class);

        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

and here is my pojo class.

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "dbname.tablenamefromDB")
public class ReleaseModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "dbcolumnname", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String release;

    @Column(name = "dbcolumnname")
    private String releaseDesc;

    @Column(name = "dbcolumnname")
    private Integer releaseStatus;

    @Column(name = "dbcolumnname")
    private Integer releaseMode;


    public String getRelease() {
        return release;
    }

    public void setRelease(String release) {
        this.release = release;
    }

    public String getReleaseDesc() {
        return releaseDesc;
    }

    public void setReleaseDesc(String releaseDesc) {
        this.releaseDesc = releaseDesc;
    }

    public Integer getReleaseStatus() {
        return releaseStatus;
    }

    public void setReleaseStatus(Integer releaseStatus) {
        this.releaseStatus = releaseStatus;
    }

    public Integer getReleaseMode() {
        return releaseMode;
    }

    public void setReleaseMode(Integer releaseMode) {
        this.releaseMode = releaseMode;
    }

}
```

Though the table exists  in db its throwing not exist.Any ideas where I made mistake.
I tried whether any aliases can be given to the table name.
I am using pojo class name only for createQuery.

TIA.

Comment: try entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a.release FROM ReleaseModel a", String.class);

Comment: try to configure entity name as ReleaseModel and try to execute it again.

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan I already tried this

Comment: @PrasadReddy I didn't get you.Can you please post here as a snippet so that it would be helpful

Comment: You mean like this @Entity(name = "ReleaseModel")

Comment: "dbname.tablenamefromDB" is the exact name of your table?

Comment: Yes Zeromus you are r8

Comment: Yes Pradeep.You need add this code @Entity(name = "ReleaseModel")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify a schema name by this way

```
@Table(schema = "dbname", name = "tablenamefromDB")
```

You have an incorrect mapping:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "dbcolumnname", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String release;
```

I think `String` can't be auto generated.
Also all your columns have `dbcolumnname` name.

Comment: then will my createQuery remain same?

Comment: Since I have used dname.dbtablename what is the need to schema over here

Comment: @Pradeep createQuery remains the same. Please, add SQL with `SELECT` from the log to the question.

Comment: @Ladynev .I am able to resolve the table exist issue but createQuery is returning empty list

Comment: Results are there in db?Any other methods Ineed to use in the same API

Comment: @Ladynev :We can make any data type as primary Key .In the table String is the primary key.I have removed the @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) still I am unable to retrieve results

Comment: @Pradeep Please, get SQL from the log and run it via a database client.

Comment: Adding the database name solved it for me ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the schema was not specified in the entity class or the user did not login using proxy. If the user login using a proxy access i.e. userName[schemaName] they do not need to specify schema in the entity class. But if the user login using just the userName, they need to specify the schema in the entity. This is to specify where the table can be found in the database.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).